# Unable to restore postgresql data dump for Django app hosted on Azure VM

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, django, restore

I am trying to restore a postgres data dump for a Django app of mine. The data dump was extracted from Heroku, and pg_restore is being run on an Azure VM with Linux on it. There are around 40 tables and the total size doesn't exceed 2GB. I've tried two approaches; both have failed. **Can an expert point out what might be the problem here?** Note that the postgres data dump is called `latest.dump` and resides at `/home/myuser/` in my Linux VM.

**APPROACH 1:**

I switch user to `postgres` via `sudo su postgres` and then go into `psql`. There I run `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`. Next I quit `psql`, and run the following command from user postgres: `pg_restore latest.dump -d mydatabase -U postgres`. The process is run, but in the end I get:

> WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 75

Virtually all the errors I got were of the **'role does not exist'** type:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 241; 1259 44416 TABLE links_grouptraffic uauvuro0s8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "uauvuro0s8b9v4" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE public.links_grouptraffic OWNER TO uauvuro0s8b9v4;
```

Note that 'uauvuro0s8b9v4' is the user on heroku; I haven't created such a user on Azure.
When I run my Django app at example.cloudapp.net, and I see a **permission denied error**. Full body is something like:

> Exception Type:   DatabaseError Exception Value:
>
> permission denied for relation links_link
>
> Exception Location:
>     /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py
>   in execute, line 54

**APPROACH 2:**

This time, I again create a fresh database via `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;` in `psql`. Then I come out from psql, and run `python manage.py syncdb` (notice I didn't do that in APPROACH 1). A bunch of tables that are created as a result. I select `yes` to 'would I like to create a superuser'. I give the necessary details and it's created for me. Next, I quickly run `python manage.py migrate djcelery` and `python manage.py migrate user_sessions` to migrate two external packages. Thus my table structure is complete.

I then proceed to run `pg_restore latest.dump -d damadam -U postgres` again. This time the command ends with

> WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 333.

If I go to example.cloudapp.net to test my app, I get no error, but **no data was restored either (whatsoever)**. Following is a sampling of errors which are seen while `pg_restore` is running:

1) **Relation already exists:**

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 242; 1259 44432 SEQUENCE links_groupinvite_id_seq uauvuro0s8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "links_groupinvite_id_seq" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE links_groupinvite_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

2) **Foreign key constraint violated:**

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2572; 0 44416 TABLE DATA links_grouptraffic uauvuro0s8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "links_grouptraffic": ERROR:  insert or update on table "links_grouptraffic" violates foreign key constraint "links_grouptraffic_visitor_id_fkey"
```

3) **Relation already exists:**

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2273; 1259 16773 INDEX links_link_submitter_id uauvuro0s8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "links_link_submitter_id" already exists
    Command was: CREATE INDEX links_link_submitter_id ON links_link USING btree (submitter_id);
```

4) **Constraint for relation already exists:**

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2372; 2606 16881 FK CONSTRAINT links_userprofile_user_id_fkey uauvuro0s8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  constraint "links_userprofile_user_id_fkey" for relation "links_userprofile" already exists
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY links_userprofile
    ADD CONSTRAINT links_userprofile_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_u...
```

---

Can an expert point out what I'm doing wrong, and what's the right thing to do here?

*Note: please ask for more information in case you need it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the uauvuro0s8b9v4 user prior to restore the database or the pg_restore will raise such errors (as this user's owns a lot of relations, in your case).

In psql try:

```
CREATE USER uauvuro0s8b9v4 WITH PASSWORD '12334444';
```